# Jersey RxJava client and collection of resource endpoints

Tags: java, rest, rx-java, jersey-client, hateoas

I'm very very new to RxJava and I'm still trying to understand the data flow but I want to know if this is possible before heading to far down the rabbit hole.

**The goal:** to decouple API resources and allow them to be distributed, as well as providing flexibility to the clients (web/mobile) to fetch data based on the href links provided to only a few 'known' API endpoints.

I've got a collection of JSON objects from one API where each json has an 'href' field that provides a link to the API resource where the full details of the data can be retrieved.  For example:

```
{
   {
      name: "assassins_creed",
      href: "games/assassins_creedId123"
   },
   {
      name: "bioshock",
      href: "games/bioshockId456"
   },
   {
      name: "clean_code",
      href: "books/clean_codeId789"
   },
   {
      name: "christmas",
      href: "events/xmas001"
   }
}
```

After retrieving this collection, I'd like to make a call to the appropriate resource using that href value and store the result in a collection such as a JSON array.

I'm mapping the Strings from the list of JSON objects into another list then I'm attempting to add them into an Observable so that I can retrieve each resource asynchronously into the same response.

I've been using the [Jersey example](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.25/examples/rx-client-java8-webapp) as reference and I'm concerned that its not able to take dynamic href links and return the response I would like.

So far I stopped at:

```
@Override
public List<JSONObject> getUsersDashboard(TokenModel token, String userId, @Suspended final AsyncResponse async) {
    List<JSONObject> list = //Database request to get items for userId
    List<String> hrefLinks = list.stream()
            .map(e -> (String) e.get("href"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    final Queue<String> errors = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    Observable.just(new JSONArray())
            .zipWith(dashboard(token.getAccessToken(),"plhUrl", errors), (array, objects) -> {
                array.add(objects);
                return array;
            })
            .subscribe(response -> {
                //errors?
                async.resume(response);
            }, async::resume);
}

private Observable<List<JSONObject>> dashboard(String access, String urlFragment, Queue<String> errors) {
     Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
     return RxObservable.from(client).target(urlFragment).request()
            .header("Authorization", access)
            .rx()
            .get(new GenericType<List<JSONObject>>(){})
            .onErrorReturn(throwable -> {
                errors.offer(throwable.getMessage());
                return Collections.emptyList();
            });
}
```

I was hesitant to put this into a for loop to create Observables for each hrefLinks entry.

How can I get the responses from multiple resources into a single coherent response for the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flatMap` operator is the thing you are looking for. You can emit the href links in a stream so that in flatMap operator you convert each link into a new observable which propagates its result into the original stream. I think this is exactly the behavior you described.

EDIT:
Retrofit library provides nice interface to create observables from links. To elaborate more on your example, you first  need to transform the collection object into some kind of Iterable using `map` operator. Once you have an interable, use `flatMap` to create an observable of items that belong to the Iterable using `Observable.from()`. This will emit the links as separate emissions. You then use `flatMap` again to transform each link into an observable of network request which forwards the emission back to the original stream.

```
getCollectionObjectObservable()
  .map(result -> iterable) // transform the object into Iterable( ie. List ) 
  .flatMap(iterable -> Observable.from(iterable))
  .flatMap(link -> createRequestObservable(link))
  .subscribe(result -> /* process the result of each item here */ )
```

Comment: getCollectionObjectObservable(): is this a method in the Retrofit library?

Comment: After some more work and help, I've got it working, thanks!